# Pandas: select rows where two columns are different

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe as below

```
a  b  c  
1  1  45
0  2  74
2  2  54
1  4  44
```

Now I want the rows where column a and b are not same. So the expected outpu is

```
a  b  c 
0  2  74
1  4  44
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `df[df['a'] != df['b']]`?

Comment: possible duplicate (generalisation): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am a fan of readability, use `query`:

```
df.query('a != b')
```

Output:

```
   a  b   c
1  0  2  74
3  1  4  44
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['a'] != df['b']]
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `nunique`

```
df.loc[df[['a','b']].nunique(1)>1]
Out[335]: 
   a  b   c
1  0  2  74
3  1  4  44
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
df.loc[df['a']!=df['b']]
```

Comment: it's a duplicate answer from the same page.