# Delete rows with equal values in one column and different values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has repeated values in one column (col_a) and repeated values in another column (col_b).

I want to select only the rows that have the same value in one column (col_a) but different values in another column (col_b).

Original dataframe

```
  col_a col_b col_c
0   1    2     1
1   1    2     1
2   3    20    1
3   3    18    1
4   3    20    1
5   3    18    1
```

Desired dataframe

```
  col_a col_b col_c
2   3    20    1
3   3    18    1
4   3    20    1
5   3    18    1
```

I've tried using df.duplicate but it doesn't work because I have duplicate values in both columns. I want to select only the rows that have different values in column b but equal values in column a.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: select rows where two columns are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751140/pandas-select-rows-where-two-columns-are-different)

Comment: No, this example does not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
df[df["col_a"] != df["col_b"]]
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem. I need the dataframe to return only the rows that have the same value in col_a and different values in col_b